# How to change list of figure entry from 3.1.0.1 to 3.1.1?

Tags: floats, numbering

I am writing my report and using the `tocloft` package. I have used these commands to get desired depth of 4 digits:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=0.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\numberwithin{figure}{subsection}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Intro}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{1.jpg}
\caption{my fig 1}
\end{figure}

\subsection{file}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{1.jpg}
\caption{my fig 2}
\end{figure}

\subsubsection{list}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{1.jpg}
\caption{my fig 3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It gives output like this

[image]

I want figure number like

> 1.1.1
>   1.1.1.1
>   1.1.1.2
>   1.2
>   1.2.2.1

and so on

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which document class do you use? Please note that modifying the `\cftfignumwidth` length parameter does not influence the way figures are numbered. It would be helpful if you posted an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that shows how you generate figure "numbers" (likely via `\caption` statements).

Comment: i have modified my query, Please help

Answer (score 3):

Your numbering doesn't really make sense:

> 1.1.1    <-- by section
>   1.1.1.1  <-- by subsection
>   1.1.1.2  <-- by subsection
>   1.2      <-- by chapter*
>   1.2.2.1  <-- by subsection

The reference `by chapter` *should* start again from 1. To achieve a "restart numbering from every sectional unit" approach, you can use the following setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,tocloft}

\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}% Just for this example

\let\oldchapter\chapter% Store \chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \clearpage
  \numberwithin{figure}{chapter}% Figures numbered within chapter
  \oldchapter
}
\let\oldsection\section% Store \section
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \numberwithin{figure}{section}% Figures numbered within section
  \oldsection
}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection% Store \subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \numberwithin{figure}{subsection}% Figures numbered within subsection
  \oldsubsection
}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{First figure}
\end{figure}

\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Second figure}
\end{figure}

\subsubsection{Second subsection}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Third figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Fourth figure}
\end{figure}

\section{Second section}
\subsection{Third subsection}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Fifth figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to redefine every sectional unit so that it re-establishes the way the figure numbering is presented: In a `\chapter`, (re)number by chapter; in a `\section`, (re)number by section; in a `\subsection`, (re)number by subsection, and so forth.

Of course, with this approach, the numbering change is *always* associated with a restart/resetting of the `figure` counter. Therefore, within each *new* sectional unit, the figure number will start with 1.

`\chapter` is handled differently using a `\clearpage`, as this allows any pending floats to be flushed before starting the new `\chapter` and associated numbering.

Comment: Nice idea, Werner. But this work if ones like have dash instead point between figure number and number chapter, section, subsection? In this case the ``\thefigure`` also need to be changed, but how?

Comment: @Zarko: The default implementation of `\numberwithin{<type>}{<hierarchy>}` is to assume a `<hierarchy>.<type>` representation. This is followed by both [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr). For a different representation, one would merely have to adapt `\numberwithin` (or `\counterwithin`).

Comment: I know this. To achieve ``<hierarchy>-<type>`` is not simply. With ``memoir`` document class I need redefine this at each figure, which is numbered out globally defined style.

Answer (score 2):

Add also `subsection` to the reset list of `chapter` and then redefine `\thefigure` to look what's the deepest non zero counter.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % one usually wants the `titles` option
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}
\counterwithin*{subsection}{chapter}
\counterwithin*{figure}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
    \ifnum\value{section}=0
      \thechapter.%
    \else
      \thesection.%
    \fi
  \else
    \thesubsection.%
  \fi
  \arabic{figure}%
}


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
\caption{At chapter level}
\end{figure}

\section{Intro}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
\caption{At section level}
\end{figure}

\subsection{file}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
\caption{At subsection level}
\end{figure}

\subsubsection{list}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
\caption{At subsubsection level}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This assumes that you have figures that come before the first section, so they're considered as belonging to the chapter.

Figures after a `\section` but before a `\subsection` will be numbered by subsection. Figures appearing between a `\subsection` command and a `\section` command will be numbered by subsection.

Note that in LaTeX there is no “end sectional level” marker: the model is that when a sublevel starts, there is no escape to the upper level except starting a new one.

If you need something like “go one level up”, please reconsider your specification: this numbering system is already confusing.

Comment: I try your solution in one of may text. It works fine until the figure is composed with two sub figures using package ``subfig``. In this case I receive error "extra \else" ...

Comment: @Zarko If I add two `\subfloat` command to all `figure` environments in the example I get no error.

Comment: @egreg, I will make (later afternoon) a MWE and check again. Error arise in one of my regular file with my own  documentclass, which is based on memoir and it is quite complex. If I will receive error again, I will make a new question about this error.